# MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - Problems if DB tablename has hyphen

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I use in php a script to import a csv into a database table by

```
$sqlQueryImport = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$fileNewDataImportInDB."' INTO TABLE " .$sqlTableName
        . " CHARACTER SET UTF8"
        . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'"
        . " ENCLOSED BY '\"'"               
        . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

I got always the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'tbl-test' CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED
>   BY '"' LINES T' at line 1"

To test it i imported the csv directly in phpmyadmin into the DB table and it works.

Then i changed the DB tablename "tbl-test" into "tbl_test" and get no error.

**It is not allowed to use "-" in a database tablename? Or must i write a special code for it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try escaping the table name with backticks.  So your `LOAD DATA` statement would look like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE someFile.csv INTO TABLE `tbl-test`
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The full code:

```
$sqlQueryImport = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$fileNewDataImportInDB."' INTO TABLE `" .$sqlTableName
        . "` CHARACTER SET UTF8"
        . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'"
        . " ENCLOSED BY '\"'"               
        . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```